# redirecting multiple mod-rewrite rules to one

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I don't know how to title the question, but here's my problem.

I'm trying to turn multiple rules into one rule pointing to one page.

The website has a catalog of photos which can be accessed preferably with the following url structure and the image numbers must start with zero:

(insert base url)/photocategoryname/month-01-2014/image/1

I want (insert base url)/photocategoryname/month-01-2014/image/0 to automatically switch to and load data from (insert base url)/photocategoryname/month-01-2014/image/1

I also want (insert base url)/photocategoryname/month-01-2014/image-1 to convert to (insert base url)/photocategoryname/month-01-2014/image/1 as well because I did a URL redesign and in the past I used image-1 instead of image/1, and search engines are trying to retrieve old files.

I also want to handle cases where an extra slash is added by accident.

When I used this ruleset and tried accessing (insert base url)/photocategoryname/month-01-2014/image-1, it gave me a redirect page with the new URL as (insert base url)/photocategoryname/month-01-2014/image/1/month-01-2014/image-1.

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)/image-([0-9]+)(/)?$ /$1/$2-$3-$4/image/$5 [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)(/)?$ /$1/$2-$3-$4/image/$5 [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/(.+)$ /$1/$2-$3-$4/image/$5 [NC]    
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)/image/0(/)?$ /$1/$2-$3-$4/image/1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)/image/([0-9]+)$ /photo.php?TITLE=$1&DATE=$2-$3-$4&PHOTONUMBER=$5 [NC,L]
```

What I want to do is minimize redirects to maybe 1. I was able to get this setup working before when I used [R=301,NC,L] instead of [NC] for the first 4 rules, but that caused too many redirects and I don't want my server spending resources on handling unnecessary redirects.

Any idea what I could be doing wrong?

---

UPDATE:

Here's what I'm trying to achieve.

I want to allow people to access the same page (photo) using any one of the following URLs:

```
(insert base url)/photocategoryname/month-##-####/image#
(insert base url)/photocategoryname/month-##-####/image/#
(insert base url)/photocategoryname/month-##-####/image-#
(insert base url)/photocategoryname/month-##-####/photo#
(insert base url)/photocategoryname/month-##-####/photo/#
(insert base url)/photocategoryname/month-##-####/photo-#
(insert base url)/photocategoryname/month-##-####/picture#
(insert base url)/photocategoryname/month-##-####/picture/#
(insert base url)/photocategoryname/month-##-####/picture-#
```

and I made PHP code that can help redirect the user to the proper URL:

```
(insert base url)/photocategoryname/month-##-####/image/#
```

This old code as the second parameter for the rewrite rule works but only for the one URL.

```
^(.+)/(.+)-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)/image/([0-9]+)$
```

But this one seems to be ignored entirely on the server:

```
^([^/]+)/([A-Z0-9]+)-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)/(image|photo|picture|photograph|pic|)(-|/|)([0-9]+)/*$
```

Both lines of code end with [NC,L].

What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The way you did it before was correct, the first 4 lines should have a `R=301` for a proper redirect.

It's not good practice, but if you want make the same page available under these different URLs, you could try changing `[NC]` to `[NC,L]`

Comment: If I take your advice, and the first line of my code matches the input, then wouldn't execution stop there and then the later lines of code get ignored?

Comment: Yes. What do you want to happen instead?

Comment: See my question. I revised it for you.

Comment: regex101.com claims my new code would work if I preface the / with a \. yet in my old code, I didn't have to prefix / before. I wonder why now. I'm lost.